# Произвольные данные в url WordPress WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, url, woocommerce, redirect

Если в постоянных ссылках товаров указать произвольную базу, например /product-category/, то получается, что товар будет доступен по ссылке:
http://wptest.loc/product-category/uncategorized/test/

Но также внутри этой ссылки можно вписать любые данные и откроется этот же товар, 301 редиректа не произойдет
http://wptest.loc/product-category/uncategorized/**asdasd**/test/

Как от этого избавиться и сделать, чтобы вторая ссылка вызывала 301 редирект на первую? Либо 404.

Answer (score 1):

Можно и не указывать. То же самое будет и с обычной базой:

http://test.kagg.eu/product/**dsdsdsds**/accusantium-omnis-eaque-corrupti-modi-alias-at/

покажет

http://test.kagg.eu/product/accusantium-omnis-eaque-corrupti-modi-alias-at/

И со статьями блога будет так. Это стандартное поведение WordPress.

А **301 там есть** - откройте dev tools и посмотрите

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И детально

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]